# Celda Excel con varias lineas desde .Net

Tags: vb.net, .net, excel

Estoy volcando información desde una tabla SQL Server en un fichero Excel.

Uno de los campos que vuelco es un campo de observaciones que puede contener cambios de línea.

Si vuelco la información sin mas el resultado es el siguiente:

```
oRng = oSheet_Electronicos.Range(String.Format("{0}{1}", columna(nColumnaIniciobloque), nFila), String.Format("{0}{1}", columna(nColumnaFinbloque), nFila))
dataStr = New String(0, 1) {} ''2 Valores
dataStr(0, 0) = _fila("Documento")
dataStr(0, 1) = _fila("Observaciones")
oRng.WrapText = False
oRng.Value2 = dataStr
oRng.NumberFormat = "@"
oRng.NumberFormatLocal = "@"
oRng.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
```

[image: Resultado inicial]

El cambio de línea se realiza después del primer "." por lo que la idea es que en una primera línea escriba "ESTA ES LA PRIMERA LINEA." y en la segunda escriba "ESTA ES LA SEGUNDA LINEA.".

Esto solo lo consigo después de la asignación del valor a la celda haciendo:

```
oRng = oSheet_Electronicos.Range(String.Format("{0}{1}", columna(nColumnaIniciobloque), nFila), String.Format("{0}{1}", columna(nColumnaFinbloque), nFila))
oRng.WrapText = False
oRng.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
oRng.WrapText = True
oRng.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
```

[image: Resultado esperado]

Me resulta raro tener que hacer esto a la celda para que se entere del cambio.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Hasta donde entiendo, la primera es la forma en que Excel muestra los datos predeterminadamente. Que lo veas en diferentes líneas no significa que tenga un salto de línea.

Comment: Las dos capturas son de la misma información almacenada en un campo llamado "Observaciones" que contiene un salto de linea. Con el primer código no autoajusta el tamaño de la columna al contenido a pesar de hacer el Autofit. Si fuerzo el cambio como muestro en la segunda parte de código lo muestra correctamente.

Comment: bien, estamos diciendo lo mismo. Pero Excel no va a ajustar automáticamente el ancho de la celda a menos que lo configures

Comment: Vale. ¿Pero por que al incluir en mi código la segunda parte, el resultado es el esperado como muestro en la segunda captura? Lo único que hago es dejarlo en el estado original pero pasando la propiedad Wrapped por False primero.

Answer (score -2):

Concatena el caracter de control que te da por resultado la función

```
CARACTER(10)
```

y te dará un salto de linea.

Ej:

```
mistring1 + CARACTER(10) + mistring2 + CARACTER(10)
```

Resultado:

```
mistring1
mistring2
```